# Serialize to file or use database for dropdown values?

Tags: php

In my php application, I use a number of different values for different number dropdown which should be editable from backend but it is less frequently edited. Is it a better approach to use a table for each of those dropdowns, that would make number of tables to go huge. Or use files saving the dropdown values as serialized array. Is file access expensive than database access? I am seeking suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File access would be less expensive than DB access although serialization and deserialization is rather expensive.

Why you just don't store them in some specific PHP files, arrays would be the fastest.

Comment: Because I wanna make it simple for my client to make changes.

Comment: database would be the simplest then just make only one table to store this with a `type` field

Answer (score 1):

Use database tables, but cache (eg using APC or memcache) the dropdowns, and set up your editor to rebuild the cached entry when changes are made

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a table for each drop down, you can put them all in 1 table. If all the tables would have the same structure, then just create 1 table and add a field to indicate which drop down the record is for.

I would suggest using a database, you can restrict access much better that way. You also don't have to deal with the user possible breaking the data structure if you just use files. The database call isn't that expensive. The act of connecting to the database is more expensive than the query. If you are already connected, an extra query isn't call to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is file access expensive than database access?

That can not be specifically answered. This depends on your configuration a lot. However, if you store most (if not all) of your data already in the database, I would even prefer the database if it's more expensive. Because you have all data in one place which is cheaper in case you need to change things. You have your stuff better structured then.

> Is it a better approach to use a table for each of those dropdowns, that would make number of tables to go huge. Or use files saving the dropdown values as serialized array.

There is a third alternative, you can store the serialized value of the dropdown into the database. That's not really good database design, but does work quite well. If you have problems to decide and/or you want to change it later, first of all create yourself a set of functions you can use in your code to read and update the dropdown box store with a normalized interface:

```
function dropdown_list_get($ID)
{
    # however you retrieve it.
    return array(/* key => value pairs of dropdown value => label */);
}

function dropdown_list_set($ID, array $list)
{
    # however you store it, 
    # $list array must be the same format as in dropdown_list_get.
}
```

You then have made the way of storing a bit more de-coupled from your scripts logic and you can change the details of how you store the dropdown list later on w/o changing the rest of your script.